# How can I determine the closed loop transfer function matrix algebraically for this block diagram?

Tags: linear-algebra, control-theory, signal-processing, linear-control, z-transform

I am checking some algebra from this paper

- James Anderson, John C. Doyle, Steven Low, Nikolai Matni, [System Level Synthesis](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.1904.01634), 2019.

Specifically, **I want to understand how transfer functions from $(\delta_x, \delta_y, \delta_u)$ to $(x, u, \hat{\delta}_x)$ in Equation (4.11) is derived in detail**.

I was able to compute the first column to match the paper correctly. However, I am struggling to get anything close for transfer functions in the other columns.

For example, for the transfer function from $\delta_y$ to $x$, which would correspond to the first row and second column of the transfer function matrix, I was trying to obtain the answer using the following steps but failed.

Assume $\delta_x = 0$, and $\delta_u = 0$. From the figure, I have following equations:

$$y = x + \delta_y \tag{1}$$

$$x = \frac{1}{z}(Ax + B_{2}u) \tag{2}$$

$$u = \tilde{\Phi}_{u} \hat{\delta}_x \tag{3}$$

$$\hat{\delta}_x = y - \hat{x} \tag{4}$$

$$-\hat{x} = \tilde{\Phi}_{u} \hat{\delta}_{x} \tag{5}$$

From (2), $(zI - A)x = B_{2} u$. This gives $x = (zI - A)^{-1} B_{2} u$.
From the relation,  $\tilde{\Phi}_{u} = z \Phi_u$ as seen from the figure's caption, I can substitute $u = z \Phi_u \hat{\delta}_{x}$ into the $x$ equation above.
Then, $x = (zI - A)^{-1} B_{2} z\Phi_{u}\hat{\delta}_{x}$. Subsequently, I would then substitute the equations (4), (1), and (5) to obtain the following:

$x = (zI-A)^{-1}B_{2}z\Phi_{u}(y-\hat{x})$ by substituting (4) into $\hat{\delta}_x$,

$x = (zI-A)^{-1}B_{2}z\Phi_{u}(x + \delta_{y}-\hat{x})$ by substituting (1) into $y$,

$x = (zI-A)^{-1}B_{2}z\Phi_{u}(x + \delta_{y} + \tilde{\Phi}_{u}\hat{\delta}_{x})$ by substituting (5) into $-\hat{x}$.

But then I am trapped in the loop, I don't know how to eliminate some variables here.

---

[image: The block diagram from the linked paper]

---

## Edit

**Calculations based on a comment from @KBS:**

We have two transfer function matrices:

$$\begin{bmatrix}z_1\\w_{21}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\Sigma_{11}&\Sigma_{12}\\\Sigma_{21}&\Sigma_{22}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}w_1\\w_{12}\end{bmatrix} \tag{6}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}z_2\\w_{12}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\Gamma_{11}&\Gamma_{12}\\\Gamma_{21}&\Gamma_{22}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}w_2\\w_{21}\end{bmatrix} \tag{7}$$

I can solve for $w_{12}$ and $w_{21}$ by computing the inverse of the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}-\Sigma_{22} & I\\
I & -\Gamma_{22}
\end{bmatrix}$,
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
w_{12}\\
w_{21}
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
-\Sigma_{22} & I\\
I & -\Gamma_{22}
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}
\Sigma_{21}w_1\\
\Gamma_{21}w_2\\
\end{bmatrix} \tag{8}.
$$

With the block matrix inversion, the inverse turns out to be:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-\Sigma_{22} & I\\
I & -\Gamma_{22}
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
-\Sigma_{22}^{-1}+\Sigma_{22}^{-1}(-\Gamma_{22} + \Sigma_{22}^{-1})^{-1}\Sigma_{22}^{-1} & \Sigma_{22}^{-1}(-\Gamma_{22} + \Sigma_{22}^{-1})^{-1}\\
(-\Gamma_{22} + \Sigma_{22}^{-1})^{-1}\Sigma_{22}^{-1} & (-\Gamma_{22} + \Sigma_{22}^{-1})^{-1}
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Then, I now have explicit expressions for $w_{12}$ and $w_{21}$ as follows:
$$
w_{12} = \bigg(-\Sigma_{22}^{-1}+\Sigma_{22}^{-1}(-\Gamma_{22} + \Sigma_{22}^{-1})^{-1}\Sigma_{22}^{-1}\bigg)\Sigma_{21}w_1 + \bigg(\Sigma_{22}^{-1}(-\Gamma_{22} + \Sigma_{22}^{-1})^{-1}\bigg)\Gamma_{21}w_2.
$$
$$
w_{21} = \bigg((-\Gamma_{22} + \Sigma_{22}^{-1})^{-1}\Sigma_{22}^{-1}\bigg)\Sigma_{21}w_1 + \bigg((-\Gamma_{22} + \Sigma_{22}^{-1})^{-1}\bigg)\Gamma_{21}w_2.
$$

$w_{12}$ and $w_{21}$ are now in terms of transfer functions $\Sigma_{ij}$ and $\Gamma_{ij}$, and can be substituted into $z_1$ and $z_2$, resulting in the following expressions:
$$
z_1 = \Sigma_{11}w_1 + \Sigma_{12}\bigg(-\Sigma_{22}^{-1}+\Sigma_{22}^{-1}(-\Gamma_{22} + \Sigma_{22}^{-1})^{-1}\Sigma_{22}^{-1}\bigg)\Sigma_{21}w_1 + \bigg(\Sigma_{22}^{-1}(-\Gamma_{22} + \Sigma_{22}^{-1})^{-1}\bigg)\Gamma_{21}w_2.
$$

$$
z_2 = \Gamma_{11}w_2 + \Gamma_{12}\bigg((-\Gamma_{22} + \Sigma_{22}^{-1})^{-1}\Sigma_{22}^{-1}\bigg)\Sigma_{21}w_1 + \bigg((-\Gamma_{22} + \Sigma_{22}^{-1})^{-1}\bigg)\Gamma_{21}w_2.
$$

So, I can see that I can get the general map from $w_1$ and $w_2$ to $z_1$ and $z_2$ as KBS suggested.

**However, this leaves me with defining $\Sigma_{ij}$ and $\Gamma_{ij}$, which I find equally difficult.**

I tried to obtain $\Sigma_{21}$ and $\Sigma_{22}$ below, and wondering if I am in the right direction:

From the figure, I have

$$x = \frac{1}{z}(\delta_x + Ax + B_2 u),$$

which gives me $$x = (zI - Ax)^{-1}(\delta_{x} + B_{2}u).$$

By matching with the equation $x = \Sigma_{21}\delta_x + \Sigma_{22}u$, which is from $z_{1} = \Sigma_{21}\delta_x + \Sigma_{22}u$, I can deduce that
$\Sigma_{21} = (zI-A)^{-1},$ and $\Sigma_{22} = (zI - A)^{-1}B_2.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I give the general idea. The rest will be left to you. Assume that we have the following systems

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
z_1\\
w_{21}
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
\Sigma_{11} & \Sigma_{12}\\
\Sigma_{21} & \Sigma_{22}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
w_1\\
w_{12}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
z_2\\
w_{12}
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
\Gamma_{11} & \Gamma_{12}\\
\Gamma_{21} & \Gamma_{22}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
w_2\\
w_{21}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and you want to find the map $(w_1,w_2)\mapsto(z_1,z_2)$. So, all you have to is eliminate the loop signals $w_{12}$ and $w_{21}$ from the interconnection. You can find the general expression for this mapping.

In your case, you have $w_1=\delta_x$, $w_2=(\delta_u,\delta_y)$, $z_1=x$, $z_2=(u,\hat\delta_x)$, $w_{12} = u$ and $w_{21} = x$. So, define the different operators $\Sigma_{ij}$ and $\Gamma_{ij}$, $i=1,2$, accordingly and apply the general formula you have previously obtained.

---

Edit for help.

The equations relating $w_{21}$ and $w_{12}$ can be combined into
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-\Sigma_{22} & I\\
I & -\Gamma_{22}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
w_{12}\\
w_{21}
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
\Sigma_{21} & 0\\
0 & \Gamma_{21}\\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
w_1\\
w_2
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

For the interconnection to be well-posed, it is necessary that the matrix on the left be invertible, so you can assume that here but this needs to be also checked when applying this on a particular interconnection. I guess it is easy to continue from there.

---

Re-edit. So, using the signals I have defined we have that

$$z_1=\underbrace{(zI-A)^{-1}}_{\mbox{$\Sigma_{11}$}}w_1+\underbrace{(zI-A)^{-1}B_2}_{\mbox{$\Sigma_{12}$}}w_{12}, w_{21}=\underbrace{(zI-A)^{-1}}_{\mbox{$\Sigma_{21}$}}w_1+\underbrace{(zI-A)^{-1}B_2}_{\mbox{$\Sigma_{22}$}}w_{12},$$

$$
z_2=\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
1 & K\\
0 & G
\end{bmatrix}}_{\mbox{$\Gamma_{11}$}}
\begin{bmatrix}
\delta_u\\
\delta_y
\end{bmatrix}+\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
K\\
G
\end{bmatrix}}_{\mbox{$\Gamma_{12}$}}w_{21},
$$
and
$$w_{12}=\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
1 & K
\end{bmatrix}}_{\mbox{$\Gamma_{21}$}}
\begin{bmatrix}
\delta_u\\
\delta_y
\end{bmatrix}+\underbrace{K}_{\mbox{$\Gamma_{22}$}}w_{21}$$

where $G=(I-\tilde\Phi_x)^{-1}$ and $K=\tilde\Phi_uG$. I have also assumed positive feedback in the loops.

So, the loop is well-posed if and only if

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-\Sigma_{22} & I\\
I & -\Gamma_{22}
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
-(zI-A)^{-1} & I\\
I & -K
\end{bmatrix}
$$
is invertible. Assuming that this is the case, we obtain that

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\begin{bmatrix}
w_{12}\\
w_{21}
\end{bmatrix}&=&\begin{bmatrix}
-(zI-A)^{-1}B_2 & I\\
I & -K
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}
(zI-A)^{-1} & | & 0 & 0\\
0 & | & 1 & K\\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
w_1\\
\hline
w_2
\end{bmatrix}\\
&=&\begin{bmatrix}
K(I-(zI-A)^{-1}B_2K)^{-1} & (I-K(zI-A)^{-1}B_2)^{-1}\\
(I-(zI-A)^{-1}B_2K)^{-1} & (zI-A)^{-1}B_2(I-K(zI-A)^{-1}B_2)^{-1}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
(zI-A)^{-1} & | & 0 & 0\\
0 & | & 1 & K\\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
w_1\\
\hline
w_2
\end{bmatrix}.
%
\end{array}
$$
We have that
$$
(I-(zI-A)^{-1}B_2K)^{-1}(zI-A)^{-1}=(zI-A-B_2K)^{-1}
$$

which yields

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
w_{12}\\
w_{21}
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
K(zI-A-B_2K)^{-1} & (I-K(zI-A)^{-1}B_2)^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}1 & K\end{bmatrix}\\
%
(zI-A-B_2K)^{-1} & (zI-A)^{-1}B_2(I-K(zI-A)^{-1}B_2)^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}1 & K\end{bmatrix}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
w_1\\
\hline
w_2
\end{bmatrix}
$$

which yields

$$z_1=((zI-A)^{-1}+(zI-A)^{-1}B_2K(zI-A-B_2K)^{-1})w_1+(zI-A)^{-1}B_2(I-K(zI-A)^{-1}B_2)^{-1}w_2
$$

and

$$z_2=\left(\begin{bmatrix}
1 & K\\
0 & G
\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}
K\\
G
\end{bmatrix}(zI-A)^{-1}B_2(I-K(zI-A)^{-1}B_2)^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}1 & K\end{bmatrix}\right)w_2+\begin{bmatrix}
K\\
G
\end{bmatrix}(zI-A-B_2K)^{-1}w_1.
$$

Which is the final result. It could be further simplified, I suppose, in certain cases. But this is the most general one.

Comment: Is there any standard reference for the general expression for such a mapping, or a name for this?

Comment: What mapping? They are all transfer functions here.

Comment: I worked out the general expression for this mapping you laid out and wanted to compare the result for correctness if there is any.

Comment: One way would be that you edit your question with those calculations in a separate section. Or, I can also update my answer with more details, but this will take more time as I am going to bed now :) Up to you.

Comment: Hello, am I in the correct direction for the general expression? I edited the question.

Comment: No, do not solve for $w_{21}$ from $z_1$. You need to solve for $w_{12}$ and $w_{21}$ in the expressions $w_{12} = \Gamma_{21}w_{2} + \Gamma_{22}w_{21}$ and $w_{21} = \Sigma_{21}w_{2} + \Sigma_{22}w_{12}$. Then, you can substitute that in the expressions for $z_1$ and $z_2$.

Comment: thank you I've carried out calculations for $z_1$ and $z_2$ in the new edit. I am curious, are there any obvious simplifications for those two expressions? or are they just messy like so?

Comment: No simplifications. But they can be applied to any linear interconnection.

Comment: sorry to keep bugging you sir but I am still lost  how do I determine those $\Gamma$ and $\Sigma$ transfer functions? I've edited the question with this follow up question.

Comment: Those are defined by your problem.

Comment: Answer updated with details.

Comment: @js9 I have updated the answer with all the details you wanted. In principle, you should have accepted my answer so that I could get the bounty. This is not very good practice.

Comment: I could not check this for the last 3 days for personal reasons. Sorry for the misunderstanding I may have caused. I will try to reissue it.

Comment: Do you better understand now how to proceed?

Comment: Yes, I got back to this today and following it much better now.